# Connection error in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a problem,I run application  C# and I get a error

> "A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

???
what?
thanks

Comment: Along with what @TLiebe said check check the port your SQL server is listening on and set that in the connection string. I had an issue like this before where the server was not working on the standard port.

Answer (score 2):

The error message pretty much says it all: make sure the instance name is correct (if your SQL server is using instances) and make sure your server is configured to allow remote connections.

[How to configure SQL Server to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

[How to connect to a server instance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265808)

Answer (score 1):

**Tip for troubleshooting your connection string:**

- Create a file named "testconnect.udl".
- Double click the newly created file.
- On the "*Data Link Properties*" dialog Switch to first tab "*Provider*".
- From the list of providers select "*SQL Native Client*".
- Click "Next>>".
- Complete the following information according to your desired connection:

  1. Data Source // your server name
  2. User Name + Password; check "Allow saving passwords"
  3. Initial catalog // your database name
- Click "*Test connection*".

If the connection succeeds save the database link, clicking "OK".

Open the *testconnect.udl* file with a text editor of your choice and compare the information with your application connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Check the protocols that are enabled for your server.
Run the Configuration Manager; you may need to enable TCP/IP.