# Cannot connect to SQL Server express from SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

[image]

[image]

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2005. I can't find my server name when I click browse for more but i know that my server name will be the same as the user name as in the picture below.

Comment: if this is sql express try the name: Abid-PC\sqlexpress (or .\sqlexpress)

Comment: Have you bothered to check the nearly **5000** other posts on this site relating to the same thing? Check this search URL: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+network-related+instance+error+occurred+26

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection error in sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118466/connection-error-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)

Comment: When use a local server. try with server name: (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb. It's working for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `.` or `(local)` or `localhost` for server name if you installed the server as default instance.

Use `.\sqlexpress` or `localhost\sqlexpress` if you have SQL Express.

The server name syntax is

`Servername\InstanceName`

If the instance is default you use just Servername.
For SQL Express, instance name is sqlexpress by default.

Comment: @Abid Ali - did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: May I ask you why do I have to service in my sql server2008. I view the my Sql Server Configuration Manager and go to the SQL Server Network Configuration. I find I have TWO options under it. Protocals for MSSQLSERVER and Protocals for SQLEXPRESS. 
But as I log in, nothing notice me about that so I just get serious confusion in how to enter the correct Sever name: localhost or
localhost\InstanceName. If I don't stop one service, my log in process will be complex. If you are willing to answer it.
I'm very glad to post a question, and if you know

Comment: I think you know since you r a Software Engineer at .NET 4, MS SQL 2008.(from ur profile) Please tell me if you resolve my question or not, and I will post the issue to share with people with the same confusion. Thanks.

Comment: What if the port is different than 1433? Does it go after the server_name or the instance_name? e.g. server,1434\instance, or server\instance,1434.

Answer (score 2):

Please see:

- [Solving Connectivity errors to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server)
- [Troubleshoot connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Using Local server with .Net 6 project, follow these two simple steps.

**Step1:** Check appsettings.json file with this settings

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MvcMovieContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDBName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** In SQL SERVER Management Studio you should use "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" as Server name.
[image]