# SQL Server Management Studio cannot connect using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Management studio ONLY. When I tried connecting to my local server using `Windows Authentication`, I am not able to connect.

I don't remeber the instance name.

- How to know the instance name of my SQL Server?

Secondly, i tried connecting using but there is an error:
`A network related instance occured...`

> (.), (local), local, .\sqlexpress

I also searched SO and got [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006980/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-management-studio-express) results set.

- Won't Management studio alone be enough to connect to local SQL?

Comment: What do you mean alone? If you want to connect to the "local server" it means you *have* a SQL installation too.

Comment: By 'alone' i mean is something else required other than Management studio. I am sure that this is sufficient. Am i correct?

Comment: When you open the connect window, the last option in the server dropdown is "Browse for more". Does it find anything there?

Comment: The local server tab remains blank.

Comment: This is not the place to learn how to install SQL...

Comment: We are not learning how to install SQL, we are trying to figure out as to why isn't it we not able to connect to local db using windows authentication

Comment: Flagged for migration to ServerFault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browse for more in management studio should tell you your instance name. If nothing is there, try looking at your services and ensure that "SQL Server" service is started. If you have a named instance, it will also show you your named instance in the services console. So if it shows:

SQL Server (MYINSTANCE)

You connect using:

.\MYINSTANCE

Comment: I dont see any "SQL Server" service in my service list.Plus nothing appears under "browse for more" option in Management Studio.

Comment: @Xorpower How do you now that you have an instance of SQL Server?

Comment: I still don't know that i have instance of SQL Server and thats why in my queston i have mentioned that in Q1

Comment: If it isn't appearing in the service list then you don't have SQL Server running on your local machine.